# How to disable no-unused-vars warning from terminal while using react-scripts

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, typescript-eslint

[image: ()]Also, i tried a few fixed at this site, but nothing worked..., so I thought of posting the same question again.

Comment: this is a issue in the create-react-app github repository, @ https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6958
If, some gets to figure it out anyhow, please let me know!!!
I'm really frustrated with the yellow warning..!!
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */`

You can use this line in the starting of the file to disable such warnings from cra's warnings in terminal.